# NSXMLParser accessing string values error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, xcode, swift

I have xml data like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.6.0_27" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
 <object class="java.util.ArrayList">
  <void method="add">
   <object class="impl.DictSpotIndexImpl">
    <void property="englishMeaning">
     <string></string>
    </void>
    <void property="englishWordName">
     <string> dendritical</string>
    </void>
    <void property="tamilMeaning">
     <string>Empty</string>
    </void>
    <void property="tamilWordName">
     <string>மரம் போன்ற வரைததடங்களையுடைய படி அடுக்கியற் பாறை</string>
    </void>
    <void property="wordClass">
     <string>regular</string>
    </void>
    <void property="wordConstraints">
     <string></string>
    </void>
    <void property="wordDataSource">
     <string>Source Not found</string>
    </void>
    <void property="wordImages">
     <string></string>
    </void>
    <void property="wordPopularity">
     <string></string>
    </void>
    <void property="wordTypes">
     <string>பெயரடை</string>
    </void>
   </object>
  </void>
 </object>
</java>
```

Now i want to get the values which is inside of the property tamilWordName. How can i do this.?
Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

So far i tried like this, really no idea about how to deal with the attributes.

```
//
//  xmlParser.swift
//  Dictionary
//
//  Created by Alvin Varghese on 27/Oct/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Karky Research Foundation. All rights reserved.
//

import Cocoa

class xmlParser: NSObject, NSXMLParserDelegate
{

    var element : String?

    func doParse(filePath : String)
    {
        var data : NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath)!

        var xmlParser : NSXMLParser = NSXMLParser(data: data)!
        xmlParser.delegate = self
        var success : Bool = xmlParser.parse()

        if success
        {
        }

    }


    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject])
    {
        element = elementName

        if elementName == "void.tamilWordName"
        {
            println(elementName)
        }


    }

    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
    {

    }


    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String, qualifiedName qName: String)
    {


    }



    func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, parseErrorOccurred parseError: NSError)
    {

    }





}
```

Comment: The element name is always `void` in your XML so you have to check the attributes dictionary for the key `tamilWordName`

Comment: @zisoft yeah i know that. But dont know the correct way to check the attribute name in this case. Do you know .?

Comment: Posted a code snipped as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a code snippet for dealing with attributes.

If the element name is `void` you have to check for attributes.
If an attribute with the name `property` exists, check if the value is `tamilWordName`. Once you found all the in the hierachy, set a boolean flag and wait for the next element(s) to come in `didStartElement`. Process them as long as you found the element name `void` in `didEndElement`.

```
func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didStartElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]!) {
    self.currentElement = elementName  // helper variable to hold the current element

    if elementName == "void" {
        let attrs = attributeDict as [String: NSString]

        if let prop = attrs["property"] {
            if prop == "tamilWordName" {
                // found it, now set a boolean property variable and process the elements coming
                self.tamilWordName = true
            }
        }
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, foundCharacters string: String!) {
    if currentElement == "string" && self.tamilWordName {
        // append to variable which holds the string
        self.tamilWordString += string
    }        
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser!, didEndElement elementName: String!, namespaceURI: String!, qualifiedName qName: String!) {
    if elementName == "string" && self.tamilWordName {
        // string element inside tamilWordName closed, process it here
    }
    else if elementName == "void" && self.tamilWordName {
        // void element with property tamilWordName closed
        self.tamilWordName = false
    }            
}
```

I hope you get the idea here.

Comment: let me take a look at that.